# How can I mark one of a 1:n relation as the "default"?

Tags: design, object-oriented, database, database-design, relationships

I have an "easy" question, but since I am not a very experienced programmer I would like to hear what some of you have to say.

If I have for example a Db called `MyDb` with many tables. Two of them are `Company` and `Address`.

The relation between them is that a company can have a lot of addresses (each for one office or sth)

So now I was thinking about it and was wondering how a "default" address should be implemented.

I imagine 2 different approaches:

1. Create fields `CompanyId` and `Default`(boolean/bit) in `Address` table. If `Default` is true, then this entry is the default address.
2. Create fields `CompanyId` in `Address` and `AddressId` in `Company`, which represents the **actual** default address.

This is not my specific problem, it's a generic blueprint, so to say.

So, now which is the better approach? `2` appears to me reaaaaally uggly. With `1` how could I avoid having 2 defaults as true? I mean not in code, just leaving the DB do this (like it says sth. when you enter the wrong type in a field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is usually a joiner table between Company and Address in a many to many relationship.  Let's call it Company_Address.

Company_Address would have Company_Id and Address_Id with relations to Company and Address.  It would also have an additional column; the Default Indicator.

The Company and Address tables would not have any default indicator.  The joiner table can also have other fields as well if needed.  If you change default address for a company one would update the joiner table record(s) as needed.

Comment: That's a nice approach! Thank you, will try it this way. Could then i use the same approach to relate dataFiles to Company or Address? How should I store the files (files are typical pdf, excel, word, etc..)?

Comment: So more than one company could have the same address?

Comment: No, a company can have a lot of adresses (offices, stores, whatever) but ONLY ONE DefaultAdress. An address can ONLY belong to ONE company.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is perfectly reasonable. Just have `default` field in the address table. This is a one-to-many relationship. And the "type of address" is an attribute the address table.

If you really want to a design schema to prevent multiple default addresses for one company create a third table called CompanyAddressDefault with two fields companyid and addressid. Then make companyid the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

You really have two relationships here.  `Company -> Address` is 1:n, but `Company -> Default Address` is 1:1.

The canonical way to model a 1:n relationship is to put a foreign key on the n side pointing back to the 1 side.  In other words, put a `Company id` column in your `Address` table.  You are already doing this.

The canonical way to model a 1:1 relationship is with a foreign key on one of the 1 sides.  Since `Company` is the only 1 in all relationships between `Address` and `Company`, you would put an `Default Address id` column in your `Company` table.

Note that using a "joiner" table doesn't allow the schema to enforce that there *must* be a default address.  If that's okay, and you find it cleaner, then so be it.  However, I think the "ugliness" you mentioned in solution 2 was due to the fact that you had to update two tables when creating a new default address.  Note that you also have to update two tables with a joiner table solution.  If you have to update two tables anyway, I would prefer to go with the solution with stronger constraints and fewer overall tables.